# IORef couldn't match

Tags: haskell

While writing a doubly linked list code using IORef, I hit the following problem. 
First I created a mutable Queue data type with links to queue front and back

```
data Tree a = T { prev::IORef (Tree a), next::IORef (Tree a), val::a } | Empty
data Queue a = Q { front::IORef (Tree a), back::IORef (Tree a) }
e <- newIORef Empty
q = Q e e
```

Then I tried pushing an Int value but I can't.

```
t = T e e (1::Int)
```

This returns

```
λ: :t T e e (1::Int)

<interactive>:1:3: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘GHC.Prim.Any’ with ‘Int’
      Expected type: IORef (Tree Int)
        Actual type: IORef (Tree GHC.Prim.Any)
    • In the first argument of ‘T’, namely ‘e’
      In the expression: T e e (1 :: Int)
λ:
```

It looks like Empty has a type "GHC.Prim.Any... which does not match other conventional types.  Is there any way to create Empty type that matches anything else?

Comment: This is all happening in GHCi, right? There is special behaviour you get in this context that has to do with GHCi being in the process of inferring. Add a type annotation and all will be well.

Comment: As a side note - this is a very good question, that is very hard to search for - please post back if you feel that the linked question isn't a duplicate!